# org.hibernate.MappingException: collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class `Subject` as such,

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SubjectId.class)
@Data
public class Subject {
    @Id
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @Id
    private Teacher teacher;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List<StudentSubject> students;
}
```

Its composite Id is defined in `SubjectId` class as such,

```
public class SubjectId implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private Teacher teacher;

    public SubjectId(String name, Teacher teacher) {
        this.name = name;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
    SubjectId(){}
}
```

On compiling, I get the error

> org.hibernate.MappingException: collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns: com.example.Subject.students type: component[name,teacher]

While this points the error to students element, the error occured after I removed the autogenerated id of Subject, and replaced it with combination of name and teacher.

Anyway, `students` element is mapped in `StudentSubject` class as such,

```
@Entity
@IdClass(StudentSubjectId.class)
public @Data
class StudentSubject {

    String studentId;
    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    private Subject subject;
    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    private Student student;
```

Comment: I've never done a multi-key value as a foreign key, but maybe if you use `@JoinColumns` on the `subject` in `StudentSubject` it could work.

Comment: @coladict It worked! But I don't understand why this was an issue for StudentSubject entity, while another entity(not mentioned here) was fine to add both columns as foreign key.

Comment: Probably because `Subject` class has a multi-key id, so Hibernate didn't know how to recursively map the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this error occurs, it generally means that hibernate is having problem mapping foreign keys on a right number of columns.

In above case, the `subject` entity in `StudentSubject` class was not getting mapped to two columns, that is the `name` and `teacher_email`(which is the primary key of `Teacher` table).

To fix such errors, add `@JoinColumns` as below

```
class StudentSubject {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "name"),
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "teacher_email") })
    private Subject subject;
}
```

The `referencedColumnName` refers to the name of the column in the foreign table.

Comment: But what if I deliberately want to only refer the partial key (i.e. no need of teacher_email) ?
I am facing same issue , can you please help. @registered-user

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely too late but I will answer so maybe it helps some other people. I had similar issue to yours, my error was slightly different though:

```
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: collection foreign key mapping has wrong number of columns: com.bla.bla.yourPackage..className.errorField type: long
```

In my case the error was clear enough but still took me a while to figure out. If I apply it to your case then you had a wrong 1:M mapping in this place:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List<StudentSubject> students;
```

mappedBy should be mapped by one of the fields (columns) in the **StudentSubject** class. Refer to this for better understanding:
https://l-lin.github.io/2018-11-14_jpa_onetomany_composite_pk/

So, if you change "mappedBy" to something like this, it should work:

```
//@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student.name")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student.teacher")
    private List<StudentSubject> students;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set  OneToMany in this way:

```
 @OneToMany(
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
    orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<StudentSubject> students = new ArrayList<>();
```